# Valid use of Google Mock? Testing member functions of same class

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing, mocking, googletest

If I am in a situation where I need to test a public function that might call another member function, is it still a valid test if I mock one function and test the original functionality of the other? Or does the fact that I am now testing a mock object render my test invalid?

I am only interested in testing A() below. Thank you very much for any insight

```
class RealClass {
public:    
    int A() { return B(); }

private:
    virtual int B() { 
        //perform some heavy computation and return 5 
        return 5; 
    }

};

class MockClass : public RealClass {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD(int, B, (), (override));
};

// Is this a valid test of RealClass A() since 
// I am using a Mocked RealClass here
TEST(MyTestSuite, TestA) {
    MockClass myMockClass;
    ON_CALL(myMockClass, B).WillByDefault(Return(5));
    int result = myMockClass.A();
    EXPECT_EQ(result, 5);
}

// Would I have to figure out some other way to test with an actual
// RealClass myRealClass object
```

I am expecting that the A() will test the RealClass::A() since there is no override, but I just want to make sure I am not shooting myself in the foot here by testing a Mock Object

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will work, but will not test `RealClass`, you might want to call and return by default `RealClass::B()` instead of 5:

```
class RealClass {
public:    
    int A() { return B(); }

protected:
    virtual int B() { 
        //perform some heavy computation and return 5 
        return 5; 
    }
};

class MockClass : public RealClass {
public:
  MockClass() {
    ON_CALL(*this, B).WillByDefault([this]() {
      return RealClass::B();
    });
  }
  MOCK_METHOD(int, B, (), (override));
};

TEST(MyTestSuite, TestA) {
    MockClass myMockClass;
    int result = myMockClass.A();
    EXPECT_EQ(result, 5);
}
```